# How to fetch Select statement from variable for Copy data activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have source query in Copy data activity of Azure Data Factory. Currently it is static query, but I would like to get entire statement from database and use that in Query in Activity.

I try to pass SQL statement as variable there is issue.

Lookup SQL Query for fetching Select statement:

```
SELECT [source_query] FROM [SalesLT].[configuration] WHERE [Id] = '1'
```

Query returns and set variable:

```
SELECT Count(CustomerId) Source_Rows FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]
```

Error with Copy data:

```
Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near 
')'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use the pipeline parameter in Query instead need to use `@concat` function to concatenate your SQL Query with parameters. Please refer the example below:

[image]

I suggest you to please go through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_I-PX27fNA&ab_channel=TechBrothersIT) from @TechBrothersIT to get more clarification on the related issue.